# Converting VB6 to VB.NET with SQL

Tags: sql, vb6, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to figure out how this code works because its from VB6 and I am converting it to VB.NET, The previous developer of this program told me that the `lstrvalue` is an SQL code but I don't see any common statement like SELECT, UPDATE, etc. that is why I don't understand it.

```
rs.Open "Select AccountCode,rtrim(type) as type, rtrim(left(formula,3)) as bet1,ltrim(right(formula,3))as bet2 from vwTempTableWP where rtrim(type) in('SUM','+','-') order by orderby", con
If rs.EOF Then
Else
    rs.MoveFirst

    Do While rs.EOF <> True

        codetype = Trim(rs!AccountCode)
        tipo = Trim(rs!Type)
        bet1 = CDbl(Trim(rs!bet1))
        bet2 = CDbl(Trim(rs!bet2))

        If tipo = "SUM" Then
            lstrValue = "execute sp_sum '" & Trim(codetype) & "','Working'," & CDbl(bet1) & "," & CDbl(bet2) & ""
            con.Execute lstrValue
            'Do While con.State = adStateExecuting
            'Loop
        ElseIf tipo = "+" Then
            lstrValue = "execute sp_add '" & Trim(codetype) & "','" & Trim(report) & "'," & CDbl(bet1) & "," & CDbl(bet2) & ""
            con.Execute lstrValue
            'Do While con.State = adStateExecuting
            'Loop
        ElseIf tipo = "-" Then
            lstrValue = "execute sp_minus '" & Trim(codetype) & "','" & Trim(report) & "'," & CDbl(bet1) & "," & CDbl(bet2) & ""
            con.Execute lstrValue
            'Do While con.State = adStateExecuting
            'Loop
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
End If
```

- rs is defined as new `ADODB.Recordset`
- con is defined as new `ADODB.Connection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted is building SQL statements to execute a [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure), specifically one of `sp_sum`, `sp_add`, or `sp_minus`. Your SQL Server documentation should explain what a stored procedure is, and examination of the source for them in *SQL Server Management Studio* should show you what each of them does.